# Angular Promise response returning object array instead of json string

Tags: json, angular, promise

```
return this.http.get(...)
.toPromise()
.then(data => {
    return data;
})
```

I then have a string object which I assign to the http response and return to the front end, but instead of returning the raw json response, it returns

[object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]

How do I just get it to return the json that the endpoint is returning?

Comment: Why would you need the json? angular is automatically converting it to the javascript array/object equivalent for you. If there was a reason you wanted to print out the json on the page as a string, you *could* convert it back to json.

Comment: Because for this endpoint I just want to return the raw information that's being passed into it, I have no need for the objects

Comment: then stringify the array back to json.

Comment: I believe you are trying to ouput your objects like this `{{objects}}` in the template.  try to use json pipe  in this case `{{objects | json}}` to see these objects better